Azure DevOps - How to set project overview default repository with .NET Libraries?
I am using Azure DevOps .NET client libraries to setup a new project in DevOps. How can you add a readme file to the project overview using the .NET client libraries?
I included the two other ways I have figured out how to achieve the same result below.
Using the Web App

Click "Edit project information" button.


Select the readme file you want to use.


Click Save button.


Using HTTP API call
var client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Patch, "https://devops.{{Server}}.com/{{Organization}}/_apis/Settings/project/{{ProjectGUID}}/Entries/host?api-version=6.0-preview");
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic {{PersonalAccessKey}}");
var content = new StringContent("{\"VersionControl/ProjectOverview/DefaultRepository\":\"{{RepoGUID}}\"}", null, "application/json");
request.Content = content;
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());


There isn’t a direct method in the Azure DevOps .NET client libraries to set project overview default repository. You can use the HttpClient class to call the REST API you mentioned in your project.

Assuming your project has been created, you can obtain the ProjectGUID through ProjectHttpClient. For example,

        var projectClient = await connection.GetClientAsync<ProjectHttpClient>();
        var project = await projectClient.GetProject("{ProjectName}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Project ID: {project.Id}");


Get the id of the DefaultRepository using GitHttpClient. For example,

        var gitClient = await connection.GetClientAsync<GitHttpClient>();
        var repo = await gitClient.GetRepositoryAsync(project.Id, "{OverviewRepoName}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Repo ID: {repo.Id}");


Create a HttpClient client to call REST API and use PAT for authorization.

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {personalAccessToken}");
        ...

